# write a lambda function of detect whether the first string is 'ice'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I have a regular function that can detect whether the first string is 'ice'.

```
def start_with_ice(text):
    ls=text.split()
    if ls[0]=='ice':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I wanna to change it to a lambda function but I wonder how. I can only write some lambda function like:

```
def change_lambda(n):
    return lambda x:x*n
a=change_lambda(3)
print(a(5))
```

Comment: `lambda text: text.split()[0] == 'ice'`

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ok, I got it. So if I do this, it will return a boolean value?

Comment: why not `text.strip().startswith("ice ")?` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple lambda function for your task could look like this:

```
check_ice = lambda x: x.startswith("ice")
check_ice("ice foo bar")
check_ice("foo bar ice")
```

Comment: `" ice me ist not going to return true, even if it would when using split()"` and `"icebear would "`

Comment: that's true, so using    lamda x: x.split()[0] == "ice" is the better solution.

Comment: or `x.strip().startswith("ice ")` to get rid of starting spaces and assure you are not meeting an icebear